# Recibir datos cada determinado tiempo mediante API que usa websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, websocket

Estoy trabajando con el API de una plataforma para recibir cotizaciones de divisas minuto a minuto, tengo una forma de hacerlo pero no es muy funcional y quería consultar si alguien me podría ayudar, este es mi código:

```
from iqoptionapi.api import IQOptionAPI
from datetime import datetime

velas = None
contador = 1

while True:

    if velas is None:
        api = IQOptionAPI("iqoption.com", "usuario", "contraseña") # Datos de conexión 
        api.connect()
        api.getcandles(1,1) # (id_activo, tiempo)
        velas = api.candles.candles_data # Lista con vela 1 segundo retrasada y vela actual
        print ("Intento de conexion...\n")
    else:
        if datetime.now().second == 59 and datetime.now().microsecond > 998000: # determinar cuándo sea un minuto
            print ("Peticion de velas:", contador, "-", datetime.now(), "\n")
            api.getcandles(1, 1)
            velas = api.candles.candles_data
            print (velas, "\n")
            print ("Hora primera lista:" datetime.fromtimestamp(velas[0][0]), "Hora segunda lista:", datetime.fromtimestamp(velas[1][0]), "\n")
            contador += 1
        else:
            pass
```

El problema radica en que aveces obtiene más de una cotización porque al ser un bucle aún cae dentro de los 59 segundos o incluso hay veces que no recibe nada por no caer en el rango de la comparación, trate de solucionarlo con `time.sleep(60)` pero me introduce un desface de un minuto en las cotizaciones que no se porque ocurre.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que de tu modo no puedes controlar cuando se ejecuta el código, se va a ejecutar tantas veces sea posible mientras caiga en ese rango de tiempo que tienes definido, lo que puede causar que haya veces que no se ejecute (el procesador puede haber estado algo ocupado y un ciclo del bucle no haberse ejecutado en el rango de tiempo de esos milisegundos) o que se ejecute varias veces.

Para ello existen librerías de programación de tareas, tipo cron o configurables, échale un ojo a esta librería a ver si puedes configurar uno sin perder la cabeza.

Prueba con esto: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Comment: Hola Soteck. He votado en contra porque considero que esto no es una respuesta, si no un comentario.

Comment: @lois6b con mi reputación no puedo hacer comentarios, pero aun así ahí estaba mi grano de arena para ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Bueno, no te apures, ya podrás. Pero eso no es excusa para publicar una respuesta no adecuada. Puedes editarla añadiendo el codigo de tu enlace y explicandole como hacerlo adaptado a su problema. Asi seria una buena respuesta ^^

Comment: Hola @Soteck. No te preocupes, poco a poco irás ganando reputación y podrás hacer comentarios. Mientras tanto, te recomiendo pasarte por las secciones a [answer] y el [tour] para aprender a realizar publicaciones de calidad. No te desanimes y adelante, sigue así!